# How can I fit my histogram with appropriate distribution?

Tags: plotting, histograms

I got this list:

```
list={{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}, {8, 3}, {9, 8}, {10, 5}, {11, 7}, {12, 23}, {13, 11}, {14, 8}, {15, 10}, {16, 2}, {17, 2}, {18, 0}, {19, 1}, {20, 0}, {21, 1}}
```

I split this list in two:

```
listsize = Table[Part[list, i, 1], {i, 1, 22}];
listfreq = Table[Part[list, i, 2], {i, 1, 22}];
```

I used the `WeightedData` on listsize and listfreq as:

```
weigthlist=WeightedData[listsize, listfreq]
```

I used this in aim to use the Mathematica `Histogram` func as:

```
hist1=Histogram[weigthlist, 22, "PDF"]
```

First question, how can I have the same histogram without weighting?
Second question, and it's the most important, how can I fit my histogram with the good distribution (Gaussian, Cauchy, etc.)? I read many answer but none of them helped me.

Comment: You can recreate weighted data also by using `WeightedData[list[[All,1]], list[[All,2]]]` or even `WeightedData@@Transpose[list]`. You can reconstruct a set of observations and plot the histogram with `Flatten[Table@@@list] // Histogram`. Probably you would also want to look at the documentation of `FindDistribution` (which can be directly applied like `Flatten[Table@@@list] // FindDistribution` for distribution fitting.) It's interesting that binning differs between these approaches!

Comment: Thanks Roman, it works very well!